# How to add a new module in magento 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, sellers-dashboard

How to create a new module for sellers dashboard to access from admin panel like as manage products module?
I will create a new table in the database to store the details of the sellers.

Answer (score 1):

basics for creating new modules:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/

How to add menu in admin:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186418/how-to-add-menu-in-magento-admin-panel

How to add sub-menu:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809047/how-do-i-add-a-submenu-to-an-existing-menu-in-magento